# Header/Navigation issues

Tags: html, css, header, navigation

So I have a problem and I am not sure where to begin to fix it.

I have a header and inside this header I have my navigation tags/css. It is a fixed header so when I scroll down the page the text goes under it. I'm running into the problem that whenever I try to put text on the page (below the header) I am finding I have to move the text down about 100px for it to show on the page.

So my question is how do I set the header so that no text CAN go behind it unless/until I scroll down the page?

Thank you everyone for your help in advance!

```
<div class="pageheader-cont">
<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">My page</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contributors</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
<ul id="drop-nav">
<li class="mess"><a href="#">Sign out</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="mess"><a href="#">Write us!</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Ok so here's some of the code. Looks a little messy but that's because I was attempting to get the Sign Out and Write us! to have different settings but now Home-Info are displaced. Not sure how to properly fix this.

And this is the code that I cannot do the  and

tags with due to the tags above.

```
<p class="itembelowheader"><a href="#">Items Page</a></p>
<p class="itembelowheader"><a href="#">Item one </a></p>
<p class="itembelowheader"><a href="#">Item two</a></p>
```

Comment: Including minimal code is *strongly* suggested on Stackoverflow.

Comment: ok I fixed it! Only took about 2 hours to find the problem. haha

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding the following to your css for the item below your header

```
#itembelowheader {
margin-top: 100px; // or whatever you header height is.
}
```

Alternatively leave the header normal and only take it out of the normal placement routines once you start scrolling.

Comment: Sorry about not posting the code but thank you for your help. It did work. I made a <class="itembelowehader"> and works great.

Comment: No worries, it is strongly suggested but in this case I could still answer.

Comment: Ok. wait. we have a problem. when I try to scroll down the header is no longer fixed.

Comment: hmm that is odd - that margin-top declaration will do exactly nothing to any other elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

HTML

```
<div id="header">
THIS IS NAVIGATOR
</div>

<div id="content">
TEXTS GOES HERE
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
height:50px;
width:100%;
background-color: darkblue;
top: 0;
position: fixed;
color: white;
}

#content {
height: 1000px;
margin-top: 65px;
color: black;
```

}

FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/y3aucbhv/

Comment: Ok. got it. Thanks everyone. A lot of my problem is occurring b/c I need to know how to split things up w/out them affecting one another. What I mean is I have a <ul> for my navigation with css properties affecting it. And although the <ul> is under a class when I try to make another <ul> my previous css effects the new <ul> I am trying to make even though its under its own class as well. Example:

Comment: Can you post sample code or fiddle for more detailed of your problem?

Comment: <div class="pageheader-cont">
  <div class="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">My page</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contributors</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
  <ul id="drop-nav">
   <li class="mess"><a href="#">Sign out</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
   <li class="mess"><a href="#">Write us!</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
 </div>